# How to provide the link to vector icon into resourcedictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I'm trying to use vector images in my wpf application. I have an icon "ic_document.xaml" in "Resources" folder, here it is:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="Svg63" Width="50"
    Height="50">
  <Canvas Name="Sf1">
    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="Path2" Fill="#000000"
          Data="M 7 2 V 48 H 43 V 14.59 l -0.28 -0.31 -12 -12 L 30.406 2 Z M 9 4 H 29 V 16 H 41 V 46 H 9 Z M 31 5.4375 39.5625 14 H 31 Z" />    
   </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

[image: icon in Folder]

I know that if I want to use it in my application then I should create a "ResourceDictionary" and then just copy-paste this code to it. But can I do it more simply and just provide the link to ic_document.xaml ? Something like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Canvas x:Key="IcTest">
     //Link to ic_document.xaml
  </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first I wanna answer whether u can Link `ic_document.xaml` The answer is no we cant do something like that but We can create a Style in your XAML file and use it

**Resource File**

```
<Style x:Key="MyIcon" TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 22,12L 26,12L 26,22L 36,22L 36,26L 26,26L 26,36L 22,36L 22,26L 12,26L 12,22L 22,22L 22,12 Z"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#000000"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

**View**

```
 <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="50"
    Height="50">
            <Canvas >
                <Path Style="{StaticResource MyIcon}">
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
```

Note if u have multiple themes and need to use DynamicResource then you need to use PathGeometry to set it

**Resources File**

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="MyIcon" >
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0" >
                <LineSegment Point="0,50"/>
                <LineSegment Point="100,50"/>
                <LineSegment Point="100,20"/>
                <LineSegment Point="80,0"/>
                <LineSegment Point="0,0"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
```

**View**

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="Svg63" Width="50"
    Height="50">
            <Canvas Name="Sf1">
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="Path2" Fill="#000000"
          Data="{DynamicResource MyIcon}" />
            </Canvas>
```